# How would one carboxylate CBG into its acid form, CBGA?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, synthesis

I have a project that would require cannabigerolic acid (CBGA) as a synthase substrate, but the only available chemical I can find is cannabigerol (CBG). CBG is the product of CBGA through decarboxylation at about 105 °C. Is this reaction reversible? How can I carboxylate the CBG I have available into CBGA?

Comment: Looks like you need to exploit the reactivity of the bis-hydroxylated aromatic ring. Reimer-Tiemann variation with CCl4 perhaps? But not sure, the molecule looks a bit delicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The substrate is a resorcinol derivative: a strongly activated aromatic ring, which upon reaction with a base delocalizes its negative charge on the ring, making it reactive towards acids (Eg. CO2).

[Here](https://patents.google.com/patent/EP2961402A1) (entries 130-132) good conversion is claimed (85%) in a high pressure vessel with magnesium methoxide and dry ice, or a lower conversion (40%) is reported at ambient pressure with magnesium methyl carbonate